# Android error al pasar a otro Intent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Tengo un error en mi aplicación que se produce al pasar de un Intent a otro. me sale el mensaje de que la aplicación ha tenido que cerrarse. Esto me ocurre siempre que pongo el fondo del layout del primer Intent y las imágenes de los botones pero cuando lo dejo sin diseño me ocurre a veces. 
Me aparece el error de 'FATAL EXCEPTION Thread-88'
¿Podría deberse a que la clase tarda demasiado en hacer las cosas y es muy lenta?

Comment: Es importante que agregues el mensaje de tu LogCat, especificamente donde muestra el texto "Caused by", agrega el código de como tratas de realizar tu intent.

Comment: @Ray, para poderte ayudar necesitamos mas información, como el trozo de código que estas utilizando o los errores en el log cat ya que alguna excepción debe estarse lanzando, pero ayudaría saber cual es.